# Location of managed Cloud SDK in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I use Google [Cloud Code](https://cloud.google.com/code) plugin for IntelliJ to develop a Scala JVM application (which is mostly the same as Java application). I would like to execute a few command lines using `gcloud`, which is part of Google Cloud SDK. When installing the plugin, it has installed a "managed Cloud SDK" by default, and there is an option to provide my own SDK installation instead.

As I like having the SDK managed and updated by the IDE, I would prefer not to have do this on my own just to run a few `gcloud` commands. Where is the automatically managed SDK located?

I am running on Windows 10 x64, but I guess if the answer could be provided for other platforms as well, it could benefit other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is much easier option to use a set of managed Cloud Code CLI tools, including managed Cloud SDK: use Menu -> Tools -> Cloud Code -> Tools -> Cloud Code Terminal. This opens a new terminal window where all managed tools paths are preconfigured and readily available.

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows answer

The sdk it located at `%localappdata%\Google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk` on Windows.

#### How to run gcloud

To run `gcloud` from the location open your terminal in the `bin` folder of the location above. The `gcloud` seems to be usable with any other settings necessary. You might also add the location `%localappdata%\Google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk\bin` to your `PATH` instead if you want to run `gcloud` conveniently.

#### How I have found it?

The question may look trivial, but it took my more than hour of searching both online and on my computer.

I have found it by performing a file search for `gcloud` on my system drive, which has found a `%appdata%\gcloud` as a first hit. In this folder I have found a log folder and the log files mentioned the location in an exception report.